# How to embed a user input inside a powershell function?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, credentials

I am creating a power-shell module with multiple functions , one of which needs a user input in middle of the run. how to use function to request an input without supplying it as a parameter? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tagged your question [credentials](/questions/tagged/credentials), so if you need to supply a SecureString as a parameter somewhere, you should use the `Get-Cred` command.

To get just a simple string, use `Read-Host`.

However, I personally find scripts that use `Read-Host` and `Write-Host` (and even `Get-Cred`) to be painful to use. You SHOULD be writing scripts to accept parameters. Then your scripts can be re-used for further automation. If you really want it to prompt for user input, then I suggest two scripts: one that has all of the actual functionality in it and accepts parameters or pipeline input, and the other that simply prompts for user input and calls the second.